# How to make my notepad chrome extension not lose the user's note when they close it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a notepad and I want the chrome extension to keep what the user types in a text area when they close it... How would I go about doing this? I've tried so many times but failed

Comment: First, I would read [mcve] as that will assist you in getting the best answers.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chrome.storage.local` or `chrome.storage.sync` to store extension data.

Note that you need to add it to extension manifest inside `permissions` section:

```json
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
```

It is asynchronous API - you can use it with callbacks like this:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```

I also recommend to check the official documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/